# Save Image to CoreData while CoreData synchronizes with CloudKit?

Tags: swift, image, core-data, binary, cloudkit

I am working on an App, that used `CoreData` with `CloudKit` using the default `NSPersistentCloudKitContainer`

**My current CoreData Setup:**
[image: Xcode Screenshot]

**Question:** Does this Setup work with the CloudKit Synchronization? Or could the External Storage be a Problem? Or is there any other Problem? if so, how can I achieve my Goal of saving Images to CoreData and synchronize them via CloudKit?

Thanks a lot for your Help in Advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My understanding is that this should work for syncing the images from Core Data to CloudKit. If you check out the tutorial here, you'll find they also use the External Storage option for their image

https://www.raywenderlich.com/13219461-getting-started-with-core-data-and-cloudkit

[Screeny from the demo project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WqzWI.png)

Comment: Thanks for your Answer. Looks legit.

Comment: For sure! I've been able to validate this works in my own project as well. CloudKit Dashboard shows entries for both an image that is small enough to get uploaded, and an image that contains simply a file path. Such a great solution!